# pytest/celery - Failed: Database access not allowed

Tags: python, django, celery, pytest

I'm having some trouble getting `pytest` to test a `celery` task that's part of a `django` project. The only way I can get it to work is to import the task in the test method.

```
# tasks.py
from __future__ import absolute_import
import logging
import django
django.setup() # flake8: noqa
from .celery import app
from .models import Run
from celery.exceptions import TaskError


@app.task(bind=True, throws=(TaskError,))
def get_runs_task(self, testrun_id=None):
    ...
    return True
```

---

Works:

```
# test_tasks.py
# flake8: noqa
from django.test import override_settings
import pytest


@override_settings(CELERY_ALWAYS_EAGER=True)
@pytest.mark.django_db
def test_get_runs_one():
    from ami.tasks import get_runs_task
    result = get_runs_task.delay(testrun_id='123456')
    assert result.successful()
```

---

Displays `Failed: Database access not allowed, use the "django_db" mark...` error:

```
# test_tasks.py
# flake8: noqa
from django.test import override_settings
import pytest
from ami.tasks import get_runs_task


@override_settings(CELERY_ALWAYS_EAGER=True)
@pytest.mark.django_db
def test_get_runs_one():
    result = get_runs_task.delay(testrun_id='123456')
    assert result.successful()
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

**UPDATED**: (There are more fields, but I omitted for brevity)

```
# models.py
from django.db import models


class Run(models.Model):
    run_id = models.CharField(
        max_length=15,
        verbose_name='Run ID')

# test_models.py
from ami.models import Run
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
import pytest

@pytest.fixture
def create_good_run():
    run = Run.objects.create(
        run_id='12345'
    return run

@pytest.mark.django_db
def test_inherit_values():
    run = create_good_run()
    assert run
```

I had `import django` and `django.setup()` in the `tasks.py` file because I was getting `django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.` I've since moved those to `celery.py` which is below:

```
# celery.py
from __future__ import absolute_import
import os
import django
django.setup() # flake8: noqa
from celery import Celery

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'amiproj.settings')

from django.conf import settings  # flake8: noqa

app = Celery('ami')

app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings')
app.autodiscover_tasks(lambda: settings.INSTALLED_APPS)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.start()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `pytest-django`'s `settings` fixture instead:

```
import pytest
from ami.tasks import get_runs_task


@pytest.mark.django_db
def test_get_runs_one(settings):
    settings.CELERY_ALWAYS_EAGER = True
    result = get_runs_task.delay(testrun_id='123456')
    assert result.successful()
```

I'm betting that something about Django's settings test helper isn't working correctly with pytest's way of doing things.

See the [`pytest-django` documentation](https://pytest-django.readthedocs.io/en/latest/helpers.html#settings) for information on the `settings` fixture.

Comment: Thanks Frank, unfortunately I'm still getting the same error. I should add that `test_models.py` is set up the same way and it works. It only occurs when trying to import a method from `tasks.py`.

Comment: Hm. Could you include the contents of your `models.py` and `test_models.py` in the question? Also, can you explain why you have `django.setup()` in your `tasks.py`? That's usually used for a standalone script, which `tasks.py` shouldn't really be. Could your Django setup / configuration be not quite right? Maybe try doing `django.setup()` in your test -- it might be that calling `django.setup()` is the reason importing from the `tasks` module fixes things.